# How to get attribute value in template in angularjs custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the attributes of "abc" defined as custom directive in angularjs:

```
<div abc="user">
    Access granted!
</div>
```

and then change the text inside div using custom directive:

```
.directive('abc', function() {
  var attr;
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
      attr = attributes.abc;
      console.log(attr);
    },
    template: "" + attr
  };
});
```

The result should be 'user' but it is undefined as attr is not defined at the time template is executed. So, any possible help how to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't edit the template using a dynamic loaded from the attribute, you have to use the scope in order to update your template

```
template: '<div> {{abc}} </div>', // here it's scope.abc
link : function (scope, elem, attr) {
    scope.abc = attr.abc;
}
```

Comment: thanks! and what to do for not returning any template depending on the logic of my function, so that the original "Access granted" can be visible?

Comment: That's really an amazing way to do it. Helped me solve my issue. Thanks a ton! BTW, could there be any other way to do it without having to assign it to the scope?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
.directive('abc', function() {

  return {
    scope: {
       attr: '=abc'
    },
    link: function (scope) {
      console.log(scope.attr);
    },
    template: "" + attr
  };
});
```

Comment: here the console is showing 'attr' is not defined!!

Comment: may try `scope.attr`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend your scope and add your attribute 'attr' in your scope

```
scope: {
   attr: '=abc'
}
```

and then from html you can define your attribute like so

```
<div abc attr="user">
    Access granted!
</div>
```

Comment: here the console is showing 'attr' is not defined!!

Comment: I did a mistake try this one scope

Comment: try console.log(scope)